# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

Here's my Web.xml

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

my servlet-context.xml

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springexample.controller.impl" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And lastly the Handler class. which is under com.springexample.controller.impl

```
@Controller
public class IndexControllerImpl implements IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {

        return "index";
    }
}
```

However on going to `localhost:8080/projectname/`

it returns a 404 error.

```
Jul 27, 2013 8:18:31 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tasklist/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
Jul 27, 2013 8:18:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tasklist/index] in DispatcherServlet with name '
```

Here is my project structure

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: What do you expect this : `/tasklist/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp` to hit ?

Comment: try `@RequestMapping(value="/")`

Comment: @TheNewIdiot that is supposed to be the view.

Comment: Do you have the index.jsp under /WEB-INF/views/ ?

Comment: yes I do. It's here. I am wondering how come Spring is not seeing it.

Comment: maybe try to add views to deployment assembly in project properties

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: Wow it work. but why?

Comment: Spring couldn't determine request type, POST or GET

Comment: @donatello Like GET and POST are the only two request methods available ;) It shouldn't matter really. Leaving out the RequestMethod argument means it will take all of them (GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, TRACE).

Comment: @Bart so what was real problem?

Comment: A had similar problems with Spring 2.5.x. Upgrading to 3.x solved all of them. Spring 2.5 was very quirky when it came to URL-matching.

Comment: Are you sure, the only change you did was add request method to the request mapping annotation? I find it hard to believe that mentioning the request method was mandatory for you. What version of spring are you using?

Answer (score 40):

With the web.xml configured they way you have in the question, in particular:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ALL requests being made to your web app will be directed to the `DispatcherServlet`. This includes requests like `/tasklist/`, `/tasklist/some-thing.html`, `/tasklist/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`.

Because of this, when your controller returns a view that points to a `.jsp`, instead of allowing your server container to service the request, the `DispatcherServlet` jumps in and starts looking for a controller that can service this request, it doesn't find any and hence the `404`.

The simplest way to solve is to have your servlet url mapping as follows:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Notice the missing `*`. This tells the container that any request that does not have a `path info` in it (urls without a .xxx at the end), should be sent to the `DispatcherServlet`. With this configuration, when a `xxx.jsp` request is received, the `DispatcherServlet` is not consulted, and your servlet container's default servlet will service the request and present the jsp as expected.

Hope this helps, I realize your earlier comments state that the problem has been resolved, but the solution CAN NOT be just adding `method=RequestMethod.GET` to the `RequestMethod`.

Comment: I think Spring's documentation is partly responsible for this confusion. They use this web.xml piece
    `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/example/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`
as an example, without any warning that the resolved views might go back to the dispatcher again if servlet mapping is not carefully configured. Most people would just remove the `example` part and that's how they got this strange problem.

Comment: You're a god and I am not and I just thought that you should know.

Comment: You are too kind @asteri

Comment: what if I want .json to be served by the dispatcher servlet. do I have to explicitly map the url pattern?

Comment: @TharinduVishwanath yes, you will need a url pattern if you want .json requests to be served by dispatcher servlet

Comment: Crazy. Thank you @AkshaySinghal. You made my working day a bit shorter today.

Comment: @Christian happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem....
I change my project name and i have this problem...my solution was the checking project refences and use `/` in my web.xml (instead of `/*`)

Answer (score 1):

First check whether the java classes are compiled or not in your [PROJECT_NAME]\target\classes directory.

If not you have some compilation errors in your java classes.

Comment: although it's not necessary that compiled classes should be there in target folder (unless you are using maven), but thanks for the hint!!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the Model object in your index method and it will work-

```
@RequestMapping("/")

public String index(org.springframework.ui.Model model) {

 return "index";

    }
```

Actually the spring container looks for a Model object in the mapping method. If it finds the same it will pass the returning String as view to the View resolver.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hey Please use / in your web.xml (instead of /*)

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**change to:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added META-INF folder with context.xml contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/SpringGradleDemo"/>
```

SpringGradleDemo is my project name and it work. 
My servlet-mapping is "/" 
I read it here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html