# Configure ViewResolver with Spring Boot and annotations gives No mapping found for HTTP request with URI error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I'm trying to make "hello world" application with gradle, spring boot and spring mvc with the simplest view resolver and html.

I started from the [thymeleaf spring  boot example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) and I just wanted to remove thymeleaf to make a simpler mvc application using pure html and InternalResourceViewResolver. I have a single greeting.html I want to serve which is located at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. When I run the app I get

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/greeting.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

This is a common error and there are a lot of answers on the web but nothing seems to help.

Here is my Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my GreetingController.java

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

Here is my MvcConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I run it with `gradle bootRun`

Here is the repo with the code: https://github.com/driver-pete/spring-mvc-example

Here are some more clues:

- Thymeleaf view resolving works fine
- InternalResourceViewResolver resolves to the right path
- WEB-INF and greeting.html seems to be present in the war file
- I do not have jsp or jstl so I do not miss those jars as some might suggest

My hypothesis is that dispatcher servlet somehow get configured to serve on /* instead of / like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897790/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-spring-mvc) and everywhere. However I don't have web.xml so those advices do not apply here. I see a lot of examples how to configure dispatcher servlet programmatically but I want to keep my app at minimum and I suspect that spring boot is supposed to configure it ok since it works fine with thymeleaf.

Comment: Setting view resolver prefix and suffix can be simplified by putting these properties in application.properties file:     spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/     
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You only need to enable the default servlet, this is done by adding the following to your `MvcConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }    
}
```

Essentially what is happening is Spring does not know how to handle the handling of such content natively(could be a jsp say), and to this configuration is the way to tell it to delegate it to the container.

Comment: Thank you! This does resolve the error. However somehow documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html somehow gives the impression that spring can handle html and jsps out of the box. It looks like falling back to default servlet is described as a possibility but not the normal way of serving jsps. What am I missing?

Comment: Also the similar error with web.xml is usually resolve itself after changing DispatcherServlet mapping. Why is annotation configuration different? What am I missing?

Comment: Compared to adding "tomcat-embed-jasper", which fixes the problem for me, your solution leads to the .jsp being displayed "raw": It's a raw output of the jsp file including all tags and not rendered as html.

Comment: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated since Spring 5; use `WebMvcConfigurer` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552835/the-type-webmvcconfigureradapter-is-deprecated

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  is depreciated you might want to implement WebMvcConfigurer

Answer (score 18):

View resolver can also be configured in `application.properties` file of Spring-Boot web applications, something like below:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: simple and clean way to configure view resolver as jsp

Answer (score 15):

After investigating more I discovered an alternative solution that works without adding configureDefaultServletHandling method. You need to add an embedded tomcat jsp engine to build.gradle:

```
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
```

As opposed to configureDefaultServletHandling method this solution works not only with plain html but also with jsp.

All solutions are available at: https://github.com/driver-pete/spring-mvc-example
This solution is available on master.
Biju's solution is on DefaultServletHandling_solution branch.

Comment: thank you very much :) i had a source code based on an old spring mvc frameworks , and i wanted to migrate it to new spring mvc based on spring boot for better and easy development and deployment . You saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring above 5.0, then  use `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`
instead of
`org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalResourceViewResolver`
in your bean definition