# How to configure spring boot mvc app for JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot ( and servlet 3.0 ).  I am trying to create spring mvc project with JSP as view. When I return a view from my controller it is not getting resolved as JstlView.

Here is what I did:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping( value="/main" , method = RequestMethod.GET  )
    public String main(){
        return "main";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value="/" , method = RequestMethod.GET  )
    public String welcome(){
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

---

Created both .jsp files in `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp` .

After googling I found that I need to specify this in application.properties So I added following in props:

---

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp


logging.level.org.springframework: TRACE
logging.level.com: TRACE
```

Even after this it is not working. Here is the trace.

```
2016-04-24 19:54:49.016 TRACE 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Invoking [MainController.welcome] method with arguments []
2016-04-24 19:54:49.016 TRACE 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [welcome] returned [welcome]
2016-04-24 19:54:49.020 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2016-04-24 19:54:49.020 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'welcome'
2016-04-24 19:54:49.022 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'welcome'
2016-04-24 19:54:49.022 TRACE 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceViewResolver   : Cached view [welcome]
2016-04-24 19:54:49.022 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'welcome'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2016-04-24 19:54:49.022 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'welcome'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-04-24 19:54:49.022 TRACE 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Rendering view with name 'welcome' with model {} and static attributes {}
2016-04-24 19:54:49.026 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'welcome'
2
```

As you see in the trace, this is trying to resolve /jsp/welcome.jsp as InternalResourceView instead of JstlView. Eventually it fails as 404.

What other steps I need to follow?  Is there any tutorial for SpringBoot-mvc with jsp ?

P.S.  I can create spring mvc app with jsp using web.xml ( using JstlView in my config file ).  But I can't find any tutorial for Spring boot mvc with jsp.

Comment: Though I am not familiar with Spring Boot, (I prefer Spring development the "legacy" way), have a look into [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953245/configure-viewresolver-with-spring-boot-and-annotations-gives-no-mapping-found-f). Might help. We do need an `InternalResourceViewResolver` bean for the views to be resolved. You need an equivalent of that in a Spring Boot Application.

Comment: Spring Boot has a [JSP sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) that may be helpful here

Comment: Try to use official application builder http://start.spring.io to configure your application (by default it uses JSP template engine).

Answer (score 19):

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
```

also needed and your pages should be at /webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/

+

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Wasn't working for me, spring boot 1.4.3-RELEASE, until i added the viewResolver then works

Answer (score 6):

Assuming it is embedded Tomcat,

You need to have followings in your `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Embedded Tomcat core package has no JSP rendering support.

Answer (score 2):

You do not require the ViewResolver. pom.xml needs the mentioned dependencies as told by Yura and place the jsp files in src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to use jsp as view in spring boot(which by default has tomcat server) we need to add the following to our pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

we need to add our pages inside

> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view

After this we can specify the location for our jsp pages in application.properties

```
  spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
  spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create webapp/WEB-INF/views {Name the last folder as U Like }
   under src/main
2. add jstl jar
3. add following two lines in application.properties

   spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/views/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp

   Run As Spring Boot App ..U are good to go !

   For More U can consult my this project on github :
   https://github.com/SudipBiswasRana/Using-JSP-As-View-For-Spring-Project