# SpringBoot : No matching bean found exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

My login page in my first SpringBoot Application:

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class MainGate extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainGate.class);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Booting .. ");
        SpringApplication.run(MainGate.class, args) ;
    }

}
```

**My Gradle File**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://masked_domain/repository/external-proxy-group/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
}
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.arun'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Implementation-Title': 'Arun Spring Boot Application',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
            'Built-Date': new Date(),
            'Main-Class':  'com.arun.MainGate',
            'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version')
        )
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://masked_domain/repository/external-proxy-group/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Application Property file**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

**Resources folder**

[image]

**Controller Class**

```
@Controller
public class CommonController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
        System.out.println("Reached the homeContoller");
        return "sso_arch" ;
    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
 017-10-20 17:01:28.568 TRACE 6704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Invoking 'com.arun.controller.CommonController.home' with arguments [{}]
Reached the homeContoller
2017-10-20 17:01:28.568 TRACE 6704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [com.arun.controller.CommonController.home] returned [sso_arch]
2017-10-20 17:01:28.574 DEBUG 6704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2017-10-20 17:01:28.574 DEBUG 6704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'sso_arch'
2017-10-20 17:01:28.577 DEBUG 6704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'sso_arch'
```

Solution mentioned in [How to configure spring boot mvc app for JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831477/how-to-configure-spring-boot-mvc-app-for-jsp) is not working.

Comment: where is the exception? Thats just a trace info that you invoke your controller and return something

Comment: now edited the exception log. please check Patrick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure spring boot mvc app for JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831477/how-to-configure-spring-boot-mvc-app-for-jsp)

Comment: I followed all the steps mentioned in this link, still facing same issue :(

Comment: is your view rendered?

Comment: No. still same exception ..

Comment: put your jsp in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` folder. not in resource folder

Comment: I did that. But still, i am getting same exception. I changed my code `resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found the right question but it doesn't seems you added the solution in the answer, you need to [Add an InternalResourceViewResolver](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial)

> This ViewResolver allows us to set properties such as prefix or suffix to the view name to generate the final view page URL:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
```

and make sure you have in dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did give  you the Bounty. Thanks

Comment: The `ViewResolver` shouldn't be necessary though, Spring boot should handle that. That's also why you need to configure the `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` properties (they're used as the prefix/suffix for the `ViewResolver`). ([`WebMvcAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/97c1365e248966e8e793091d59048573459d7600/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L224-L230))

Comment: Please check now.