# Spring Boot "No message available" error(status = 404),

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Boot with embeded Tomcat.
When it starts it logs into console:

> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/home]}" onto public java.lang.String com.vlad.pet.contactlist.webapp.controller.SampleController.helloWorld(org.springframework.ui.Model)

So I guess the URL is mapped to the controller.
But http://localhost:8090/home gives me an error 404.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    //overrides the configure() method to point to itself, so Spring can find the main configuration.
    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
        final TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions("WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml");
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

SampleController.java

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {
    @RequestMapping (value = "/home")
    public String helloWorld(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "home");
        return "base";
    }
}
```

tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/basic/basic-template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="head" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/basic/head.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYber.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning 'home' from your controller method, but I don't see a home.jsp on your project structure.

Comment: Sorry, that was typo, now edited. Controller returns "base", which is defined as tiles definition

Comment: Did you change the server port on application.properties? The default is 8080. So, if you haven't changed it, the URL would be - http://localhost:8080/home

Comment: In application.properties: server.port=8090

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by enabling default servlet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
```

Source: [Configure ViewResolver with Spring Boot and annotations gives No mapping found for HTTP request with URI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953245/configure-viewresolver-with-spring-boot-and-annotations-gives-no-mapping-found-f)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my eclipse project was showing an error. i had to do mvn install from eclipse, update maven  dependencies and then start the server from eclipse.