# spring-boot 404 error in serving .js, .css files to html templates

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and was trying to host HTML pages that use angular js.
My folder structure is :[image: My Folder Structure]

I referred to a lot of other question on SO and even spring.io guide on spring boot and what I understood was that we are supposed to keep our html templates in templates folder and all the .css, images, .js files in static folder. I have done the same, but whenever the page loads , only the html is rendered and browser get 404 for all .css and .js files.

I have include .css and .js in my HTML in the following manner :

```
<script src="/js/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/demoApp.js"></script>
```

I tried all the combinations like :
src="../static/js/socket.io/socket.io.js" or src="js/socket.io/socket.io.js"
but always I am getting 404 for these files, in the browser.

I checked the spring boot logs and this is what it says :

```
2016-07-24 21:08:05 WARN  PageNotFound:1139 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/js/demoApp.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-07-24 21:08:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:997 - Successfully completed request
```

I am unable to understand how to solve the issue, please help !!!

Note : I have not written view resolver code because according to my understanding spring boot automatically picks up static content from static folder. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Edit : Adding my pom file :

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Alexa Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
            <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.40</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: That looks like it should be correct as mine is set up this way and I do not need to refer to static.  I am using Freemarker templates of which some have Angular and it works.  Can you share the POM file for your project?

Comment: yea sure , edit done to show the pom file, @RobBaily please check !!

Comment: please show your  InternalResourceViewResolver (xml or java)

Comment: This topic might be interesting for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953245/configure-viewresolver-with-spring-boot-and-annotations-gives-no-mapping-found-f

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte thanks a lot, it was helpful, but as I answered , just extending the WebMvcAutoConfiguration class helped and I did not have to give any view resolver or create any new controller.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using thymeleaf so try to access your resources like this :

```
<script th:src="@{/js/socket.io/socket.io.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/moment.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/demoApp.js}"></script>
```

Also and if this does not work can you add your index.html.

Comment: sorry I had to udpate this, I have removed thymleaf because I am using angularjs for UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem , everything was correct but :
1) I was not extending my Application class from WebMvcAutoConfiguration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class HLACUIApplication extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HLACUIApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is how the application class should be.

2) I don't need to use templates folder because I am using angularjs and not thymeleaf. I have put everything in static folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I think you are having `html` code like below:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <!-- Main Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bar.css" />
    <script src="/js/foo.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Welcome to Foo!</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I solved the problem by adding `type="text/javascript"` to the `<script>` element. In `Spring Boot` applications it's required to define `type="text/javascript"`, otherwise it's not going to load.

The solution for your example would look like this:

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <!-- Main Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bar.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foo.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Welcome to Foo!</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case with thymeleaf, helped when I skipped '/' before 'js'.

Example, instead of

```
<script src="/js/demoApp.js"></script>
```

I've put

```
<script src="js/demoApp.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Eclipse IDE` right click on Project Properties/Project Facets