# Spring with maven, jar packaging, not displaying welcome.jsp page

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I am using Spring boot with maven jar packaging. My project structure looks like this
[image]

I am starting my project from command promt with this command: 
mvn package && java -jar target/ProjekatNekretnine-0.0.1.jar, and it starts perfect. Than I go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/users/home and I do not get my welcome.jsp page. My controller class looks like this:

UserController class:

```
package com.projekat.nekretnine.controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.projekat.nekretnine.Model.Korisnik;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="api/users")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

I think that my welcome method should return my welcome.jsp file, but instead it writes "welcome" to the page. Why is that so? What am I doing wrong?

My welcome.jsp file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is working.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So you see that it shouldn't write welcome.

Here is my pom.xml for you to take a look:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.projekat.nekretnine</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjekatNekretnine</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.30</version> -->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

One more thing, when I created maven project, I selected that the packaging should be JAR, not WAR. I don't know if I need now web.xml or other xml files, I think not. Maybe the mistake is where I put my static files, if that's the problem, can you tell me where to put tham?

And I tried to use @Controller, instead of @RestController in my UserController class, and still the same problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're doing a Web Application, you have to make a WAR, not a JAR. WAR = Web Application Archive

Comment: Add the code for your SpringBootServletInitializer class and also add if there are any other config classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour your are experiencing is normal.
This happens because you instructed your controller( specifically your rest-controller ) to return a String object when it hits /api/users/home endpoint.
If you however want to expose a page(view) in this endpoint you should configure your spring-boot to use a InternalResourceViewResolver.

You could take a look at a similar question [Configure ViewResolver with Spring Boot and annotations gives No mapping found for HTTP request with URI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953245/configure-viewresolver-with-spring-boot-and-annotations-gives-no-mapping-found-f). and apply the changes for your controller to return the welcome page.