# Spring does not show home.html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring Framework. I added `home.html` in `resources/templates/home.html`. But it is not visible when I visit http://localhost:8080. I have the following structure:

**taco-cloud\src\main\java\tacos\TacoCloudApplication.java**

```java
package tacos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TacoCloudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**taco-cloud\src\main\java\tacos\HomeController.java**

```java
package tacos;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home.html";
    }
}
```

**taco-cloud\src\main\resources\static\home.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
 <title>Taco Cloud</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Welcome to...</h1>
 <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

Whitelable error page

**localhost:8080/home.html** 
show home.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the location of your home page to be in the `static` folder :

```
resources/static/home.html
          ^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
resources/templates/home.html
```

and specify the extension in your controller :

```
return "home.html";
            ^^^^^
```

---

else you have to create a view resolver to avoid using extensions and to specify the other locations of your pages take a look at [Configure ViewResolver with Spring Boot and annotations gives No mapping found for HTTP request with URI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953245/configure-viewresolver-with-spring-boot-and-annotations-gives-no-mapping-found-f)

Comment: It did not work. I did all as you suggested. I have edited my question. But localhost:8080/home.html is working. But localhost:8080 should show home.html @YCF_L

Comment: try removing the .html extention in your return statement in the controller class

Comment: I did removed .html extension but it did not work. @m-2127

Comment: @Aman it works very file with me, are you sure you followed the correct steps?

Comment: localhost:8080/home.html is showing home.html @YCF_L

Comment: @michalk whad did you mean?

Comment: I am asking him if he configured view resolver, because if not, his endpoint will return String "home.html" - exactly what he wrote several comments above.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "templates/home.html";
    }
```

[Check more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

Comment: Add your file location "static/home.html"

Comment: It is in my question @BipilRaut

Comment: Do you have extend @Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{}

Comment: No. I have not @BipilRaut

Comment: I seen your project in pom.xml file have any error , could you please clean install your pom file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195390/discussion-between-bipil-raut-and-aman).

Answer (score 0):

Below are few different ways you can place html files in your project.(Note it is from highest to lowest precedence)

`src/main/resources/resources/home.html 
src/main/resources/static/home.html 
src/main/resources/public/home.html`

Go through [this](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/01/spring-mvc-project-structure.html) to get an idea about spring mvc project structure