# Spring Boot MVC configuration request redirected to Dispatcher again

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm struggling with the issue described here

[No mapping found for HTTP request with URI Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897790/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-spring-mvc)

Problem is once the resource resolver resolves the view, it's again redirected to the Dispatcher, which doesn't find the a method mapped to it.

For example if user requests for `/test` and resolver maps it to `/views/test.jsp`, dispatcher instead of rendering the response tries to lookup path `/views/test.jsp` again.

I have tried to change the default dispatcher servlet path to `/` (which by the way is `/` by default).

It doesn't work with Spring Boot configuration.

I would like to know if there's a solution for this without having to set dispatcher path to something other than `/` like `/page`.

Following is test code to produce the issue. (Here's github link for the Test project https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/stackoverflow/tree/master/TestMvc)

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestMvcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestMvcApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public MvcConfig () {
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%% " + getClass() + " loaded %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet);
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Adding dispatcher servletmapping");
        registration.addUrlMappings("/");
        return registration;
    }
}

@Controller
class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("test")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Following are the relevant logs

```
Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'test'; URL [/views/test.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'test'; URL [/views/test.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
Forwarding to resource [/views/test.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'test'
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/views/test.jsp]
Looking up handler method for path /views/test.jsp
Did not find handler method for [/views/test.jsp]
Matching patterns for request [/views/test.jsp] are [/**]
URI Template variables for request [/views/test.jsp] are {}
Mapping [/views/test.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@21362712]]] and 1 interceptor
Last-Modified value for [/views/test.jsp] is: -1
Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
Successfully completed request
Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Remove your `MvcConfig ` as that breaks proper integration, also do you really want to use JSPs? That would only work with `war` packaging and the jsp files would need to go into `webapp/views` in your case.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how it's breaking the configuration, removing it doesn't help ? Yes I need JSPs as I'm converting a legacy project to the Spring Boot, it has a lot of JSPs, which I'm not yet ready to migrate to any other view layer.

Comment: It's breaking because it disables (part of) the auto configuration which you probably still expect to work.

Comment: What is the correct way to override MVC configuration in Spring Boot ?

Comment: What would you need to override that isn't already configured?

Comment: I can be needed for any custom configurations like registration of another servlet, or registration of abbriviated view mappings.

Comment: Then you can extend the default you don't need to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Including following dependencies resolves the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm guessing that there was a JSP parsing error internally (Or JSTLView wasn't present) which redirect the view request to the dispatcher.

After including these dependencies JSP view is rendered successfully.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who tried other solutions with no luck, you may want to check if ResponseBody annotation is present in the controller class.

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    BO bo = new BO();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sayHello",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                    produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String sayHello() {
        return "Hellaa!!";
    }

}
```